# ReactJS - Proper way to fetch data from redux and load form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  campaign_dates: {
    dt_start: '',
    dt_end: '',
  },
```

I am submiting my form and them send an action to save the data into redux:

```
  function onSubmit(data) {
    dispatch(addCampaignDatesAction(data))
  }
```

So far so good, I'm able to save the data, but how can I load it in my form?

In my component where my form is, I tried something like this:

```
const getCampaignDatesFromState = useSelector(
    state => state.createCampaign.campaign_dates,
  )

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(getCampaignDatesFromState.dt_start !== '' ? new Date(getCampaignDatesFromState.dt_start) : '')

const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(getCampaignDatesFromState !== '' ? new Date(getCampaignDatesFromState.dt_end) : '')
```

But I'm getting "Invalid time value at format" error (my start and end date inputs is from react-datepicker)

What is the proper way to load redux data into your form?

Comment: Have you check mapStateToProps?

Comment: I'm using react hooks, tried with useEffect but same error pops up

Comment: @ShoebMirza he is using the new [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) style useSelector

Comment: The problem looks like time format related, but not react-redux. console.log(getCampaignDatesFromState) and check it's format.

Comment: @SuleymanSah getCampaignDatesFromState its an object widh dt_start and dt_end equals to ' ' which is my initial state from my reducer

Comment: I got it, I was passing an object, when I just separate them with ```const startCampaignDate = useSelector(
    state => state.createCampaign.campaign_dates.dt_start,
  )``` its working now. Thanks @SuleymanSah

Comment: @fjurr I think you can delete this question if you want.

Answer (score 2):

İf you want to call dispatch and update your store you sould add this lines on your form ;

Firstly added bindActionCreators and connect;

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
```

and then use connect method for mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps;

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourComponent);
```

now you sould define mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps like this;

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getCmpDates: state.campaign_dates
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setCmpDates: bindActionCreators(campaign_dates, dispatch),
});
```

and now you can change your store with setCmpDates or you can read dates with getCmpDates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `connect()` method from the `react-redux` library. This does also contain some hooks, but you are better off avoiding them, as they can create some strange problems and you loose all the performance benefits of `connect`.

Comment: @fjurr you don't need to use connect. There is nothing wrong with the new hooks style react-redux.